# Displaying data to populate dropdown with Django Rest Framework and AngularJS

Tags: django, angularjs, django-rest-framework

Im trying to figure it out how is the correct way to render a gender and location dropdown using the following API structure in my app with Django Rest Framework and using AngularJS for the endpoint.
Consider de following Model where Location is FK of Profile and gender has a set of choices.

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Serializers

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ('name', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
        read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at')

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('user', 'gender', 'birth_date', 
                'location', 'description', 'image', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
        read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at')

    def get_validation_exclusions(self, *args, **kwargs):
        exclusions = super(ProfileSerializer, self).get_validation_exclusions()

        return exclusions + ['user']
```

So being newby in Angular i need something like this in the ng-options of my dropdown but also i would need my serialized data being rendered with this format which is in this case is not:

```
[
{
    "user": {
        "username": "admin", 
        "email": "admin@admin.com", 
        "first_name": "Administrator", 
        "last_name": "Administrator", 
        "date_joined": "2014-12-21T17:20:49.172990Z"
    }, 
    "gender": "M", 
    "birth_date": "2015-01-15", 
    "location": [{id:1, name: "Argentina"},
                 {id:2, name: "Mexico"},
                 {id:3, name: "Colombia"}],
    "description": "algo",  
    "created_at": "2015-01-02T17:25:53.894873Z", 
    "updated_at": "2015-01-02T17:25:53.894957Z"
}
]

<select class="form-control" id="profile_location" ng-model="vm.profile.location"
ng-options="location.name for location in locations" ></select>
```

Comment: Could you show UserSerializer and I think you are missing Nested Relationship for "location" field.

Comment: UserSerializer has nothing to do here i believe..

Comment: In UserSerializer you can specify specific field that you want.

Comment: Also, in order to "append" location data to Profile you have to use Nested Relationship. Ex. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Comment: If i add Location as a nested serializer i tried doing ng-options="l.name for l in location" but im not able to populate it